# disable elements on UIView behind modal UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, modal-view

i have a UIView that is smaller than the superview so i can represent this view as a modal view when a button is clicked.

I have managed to do the following:
* add a subview to the superview.
* centered this modal view

I am now trying to make the elements behind the UIView unclickable. And also add a grey shadow te the ourside of my modal view so that the user understands that the modal view is the view in focus.

I would like to know how to achieve this.

I do not wish to use the presentation modal transition. I know and have already implemented this in other projects. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to lay a fullscreen `UIView` with a translucent gray background behind your "modal" view. Then it will intercept all of the touches. It might look something like this:

```
UIView *dimBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:theSuperview.bounds];
dimBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.5f];

[theSuperview addSubview:dimBackgroundView];
[theSuperview addSubview:modalView];
```

For future reference, you can set `myView.userInteractionEnabled = NO` to disable touch events on a view.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. 
If you have a custom view  which has custom location, you can modify it like that:

Create an instance `var`:

```
UIView* backgroundView;
```

And whenever you need it, put it behind your custom view:

```
if (backgroundView == nil)
        backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.5f];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
[backgroundView animateBump:customView.view];
[backgroundView addSubview:customView.view];
```

When you do not need it anymore

```
   [backgroundView removeFromSuperview];
```