# iPad: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds returns wrong co-ordinates

Tags: objective-c, ipad, bounds, uiscreen

`[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` returns (0,0,768,1024) even when the iPad is in Landscape mode.

It should return (0,0,1024,768) but instead it returns (0,0,768,1024).

What could be wrong?

Comment: When are you pulling the CGRect with the erroneous values? Before/during/after the rotation animation?

Comment: [This chap](http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2011/03/beware-using-uiscreen-mainscreenbounds.html) had a similar problem. Can you do like him and get bounds from a better-behaved object?

Comment: @Sold Out Activist: I am launching the app in landscape mode so it is before rotation.So Rotation is not involved in this.

Comment: Note that on iOS 8, the behavior has changed so that the value returned by `bounds` does depend on the orientation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing's wrong. This is how it works unfortunately.

See this question: [Returning incorrect rectangle on landscape application launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664980/returning-incorrect-rectangle-on-landscape-application-launch-iphone-ipad)