# Device screen width wrong when starting my Swift app in landscape

Tags: ios, swift, landscape

I use this code to get the screen width and height

```
public var width: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
}

public var height: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}
```

After a rotation the code is working fine but if I start the app in Landscape mode, the returned height in `viewDidLoad` is wrong and is 812.0, which is the width. If I rotate to portrait and than back to landscape, than the value is 375.0 which is right.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14064672), you should run your code in `viewWillAppear` and/or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  When `viewDidLoad` is called, that view controller's view is guaranteed to be loaded into memory, but it is not yet rendered.  `viewWillAppear` is called when a view is about to be added to an on-screen view hierarchy, as detailed in the [Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear).  At this point, the view controller should be able to access the orientation that the device is in, since its content views will most likely be rendered when `viewWillAppear` is called.  If your code is still returning the wrong values, you may need to move it into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which is called whenever the bounds of the current view will change.

Edit: it looks like you will need to flip the width and height values based on the orientation and their relationship to one another, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19186008), although that is in Objective-C.  In Swift:

```
public var width: CGFloat {
    //If in landscape mode
    if (UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape) {
        //If in landscape and the width is less than the height (wrong),
        //return the height instead of the width 
        if (UIScreen.main.bounds.width < UIScreen.main.bounds.height) {
            return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        }
    }
    //Else just return the width
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
}

public var height: CGFloat {
    //If in landscape mode
    if (UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation.isLandscape) {
        //If in landscape and the height is greater than the width (wrong),
        //return the width instead of the height 
        if (UIScreen.main.bounds.height > UIScreen.main.bounds.width) {
            return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        }
    }
    //Else just return the height
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}
```

Comment: I tried in both viewWillAppear and viewDidLayoutSubviews and I still have the same problem. I have to rotate the device to portrait and then back to landscape to get the right height value

Comment: Thank you. I though about implementing something similar but I would like to understand what is causing the problem, and if there is a cleaner way to fix that

Comment: @mbbf I'm really not sure as to what is causing this.  According to the documentation for UIScreen.main.bounds, (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617838-bounds) , "This rectangle is specified in the current coordinate space, which takes into account any interface rotations in effect for the device."  Is this happening in the simulator, on a physical iOS device, or both?

Comment: Not tried in simulator, tried it only on physical iOS device

Comment: @mbbf The simulator tends to be buggy with device orientation stuff, but if it's not working on a real iOS device, then there's definitely a bug somewhere.  It looks like this is related to how iOS handles launching apps in landscape according to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664980/uiscreen-applicationframe-returning-incorrect-rectangle-on-landscape-application).  The workarounds suggested there are very similar to mine.